# Добавление ссылки в шапку панели администратора

Tags: python, django

У меня есть шапка в панели администратора django
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть своя страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить ссылку в шапку для перенаправления на эту страницу?

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем.

Comment: переопределить базовые шаблоны django-admin